# Login bar disappears when I try to log in

Tags: login

I try to login but when I press enter the login bar disappears and it doesn't login. It doesn't work with guest or my profile. I still can't login. People are telling me to restore something but I don't know how.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to :

1-Restore the /etc/issue file: sudo mv /etc/issue.backup /etc/issue

2-Restore the /etc/rc.local file: sudo mv /etc/rc.local.backup /etc/rc.local

3-Then reboot (sudo reboot)

Comment: How do I go into sudo from login?

Comment: You need to mention how to do this from recovery mode or a tty.